# jQuery Mobile v1.1.0 loader/progressbar do not show on android Internet browser

Tags: jquery-mobile, progress-bar

Hello I have problem with jQuery Mobile v1.1.0. When I try to use this function.

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```

The progress indicator is not shown. The progress indicator(loader) is shown in regular browser, like FF, but in Android Internet browser, the PI is now shown. Do you have any Idea why the loader is hidden in android browser? I tested it on samsung nexus mobile phone, with the android version v2.3.4. I tried to call the function with parameters like this

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "test message test", false);
```

But this works only on my PC web browsers FF, Chrome IE etc.

Answer (score 0):

did you try the [examples](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/config/loadingMessageTextVisible.html) in the docs?

On my android 2.3.3 the loader is shown but the loader image is not animated.

If the examples work for you, be sure that you replaced/removed all old JQM files with the 1.1.0 version (css, js, images) and that they are linked correctly in the document.

Answer (score 0):

When the themeroller was deployed for v1.1.0 there was a small error with the loader images in the zipfile and the style sheet.

This was [fixed](https://github.com/jquery/web-jquery-mobile-theme-roller/issues/84) within a few hours, but it might be that the version you downloaded tries to load ajax-loader.gif, while ajax-loader.png was in the zipfile.

Getting your theme again from the [themeroller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) might fix it for you

Regards,
Casper

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The progress-dialog was not shown when doing an ajax call afterwards. I incapsulated everything except the showPageLoading-call in a timeout-function-call.

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();  
setTimeout(function() {  
...[here your code goes]...  
},200);
```

Worked for me although the animation only worked until the function has been executed (here: 200ms) but that doesn't really matter to me.